# Android ndk c++ do i have to change my whole code or can i use precompiled executables/make

Tags: c++, android-ndk, cross-compiling

As the topic says, I'm interested in using some existing c++ code. It is quite much so I don't want to change everything. That's why I'm asking if I have to change the whole code or if it is possible to include it somehow.

As I noticed Android Studio/Gradle wants a CMake file in order to include those external libraries, but my code only includes ordinary makefiles.

Is there any way to make use of the given structure without many changes?

I can't give too much information about the code because it will be too much but here is something about it:

- C++ Code
- Using Makefiles

(will add more if needed)

Methods I tried:

1. Ship code inside assets, copy it in the local directory and use then use "make" to compile it on the smartphone - result: permission denied
2. Use precompiled Unix executable - I couldn't find a right compiler yet (already tested Android standalone toolchain)
3. Use Android NDK - I didn't manage to include the existing code because the changes were too deep

In my opinion, the best way would be one of the first two options. But I haven't found a way to handle these problems, which are listed above.

What I would like to know is now:

1. Which option would be the best? Of course, if they're all possible that will depend on the problem, but some opinions would be nice.
2. How do I know what compiler I have to use?

Comment: You expect that your code and build system will be magically portable to a new platform? You can compile C++ on Android with the NDK, and you can compile it using Makefiles. Without specifics, there's not much to answer here.

Comment: Well not magically, just as simple as possible. I added some simplified information about the approaches I had in mind and the problems they caused.